# Does Apple sell European connectors individually?

Tags: hardware, power

I recently moved from the US to Europe. I'm currently using universal adapters for connecting my US plugs to European power outlets. Many of the things which need power are Apple devices. It would be nice to replace the US connectors

[image: US connector]

with European connectors

[image: European connector]

obviating the need for the universal adapters.

I expected these connectors to be sold individually, but they seem to only be included in the [Apple World Travel Adapter Kit](http://www.apple.com/shop/product/MD837AM/A/apple-world-travel-adapter-kit). Am I missing something? Does Apple sell these connectors individually?

In case it's significant, I'm in Berlin, Germany.

Answer (score 3):

Are you talking about the connectors that plug into the power supply?  I would not bother with Apple-branded connectors. They are called "duckhead connectors" and other brands are widely available, individually and in sets, online both in the U.S. and in Europe, and much less expensive than the ones that say Apple. And to my knowledge, Apple only sells them together, all the worldwide varieties in one box. Plug adapters are also widely and cheaply available.

Comment: Thanks. I didn't know the term "duckhead connector". It's useful to know the appropriate search term.